# yaws and erlang beam files in ebin

Tags: erlang, floating-point, integer, yaws

I am having problems when i have integers and float numbers in my form posts and receive these in my ebin file where i have beam files.  Hope someone can help me.

**npower.yaws**

```
   <erl>
kv(K,L) ->
{value, {K, V}} = lists:keysearch(K,1,L), V.        
out(A) ->
L = yaws_api:parse_post(A),
N = kv("number", L),
    npower62:math3(N).
    </erl>
```

**npower62.erl compiled to beam file** 
-module(npower62). 
-export([math3/1]).

math3( [N] ) -> 
        Number = N, 
        Nsquare = Number * Number, 
        {html, io_lib:format("square of ~c = ~w", [N, Nsquare])}.

**Gives me square of 3 = 2601 

instead of 

square of 3 = 9

 i have tried to use Number = list_to_integer(atom_to_list(N)) (doesnt work) 

 i have tried to use Number = list_to_float(atom_to_list(N)) (doesnt work) 

 i have tried to use Number = list_to_integer(N) (doesnt work)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can narrow down the scope which your `math3/1` function accepts:

```
-module(npower62). 
-export([math3/1]). 

math3(N) when is_number(N) -> 
  N2 = N * N,
  io_lib:format("square of ~p = ~p", [N, N2]).
```

Note we have rewritten the function quite a bit. It does not accept a list anymore, but any number, `N` only. Also, the format string you handed to `io_lib:format/2` was off totally, see `man -erl io`.

We can now attack the yaws code:

```
<erl>
  kv(K,L) ->
      proplists:get_value(K, L, none).

  out(A) ->
    L = yaws_api:parse_post(A),
    N = kv("number", L),
    none =/= N, %% Assert we actually got a value from the kv lookup

    %% Insert type mangling of N here so N is converted into an Integer I
    %% perhaps I = list_to_integer(N) will do. I don't know what type parse_post/1
    %% returns.

    {html, npower62:math3(I)}
</erl>
```

Note that your `kv/2` function can be written with a proplists lookup function. In your variant of the code, return from `kv/2` was the value `{value, {K, V}}` which will *never* be correct in your version of `math3/1`. `proplists:get_value/3` returns the `V` part only. Also note I hoisted {html, ...} to this level. It is bad style to let npower62 handle it since it should know nothing about the fact it is called from within yaws.

My *guess* is that you need to call list_to_integer(N). The easiest way to figure this out is to use a call to `error_logger:info_report([{v, N}])` and look for the INFO REPORT in the shell or in the log file and see what term N is.

TL;DR: The problem is that your values are not matching all over the place. So you are faced with numerous crashes of the function which yaws probably catches, logs and then survives. This then confuses you to no end.

Also, test your function `npower62:math3/1` function from the `erl` shell. That way, you would have found it were wrong from the start, reducing your confusion.

Comment: Worked Great!!! You give great practical answers!  But What if the number entered is not an integer?  What if its a float? e.g. 1.2?  How do a situation where we want to handle an integer OR a float (in our npower.yaws file?

Comment: I'd probably do use `string:to_float` and `string:to_integer`. The trick is to test the integer first and then try the float if there is something which did not get parsed.

Comment: @IGIVECRAPANSWERS: `none =/= N` will not assert e got walue. `false none =:= N` or `true = none =/=N` would.